# window.close not working for Twitter Website

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code that opens a Twitter URL (window.open()), but I think Twitter is clearing/erasing my window reference that's why I can no longer control my window or to close it using window.close(). What will be the workaround for this?

I tried to console.log this, the window is always null if the website loads up.
Here's the code:

```
var windows = {};

function OpenWindow(id, url, title, w, h, l) {
  $.each(windows, function(index, value) {
    if (windows[index].closed) {
      $('#' + index + '').css("background-color", "");
    }
  });

  $('#' + id + '').css("background-color", "#F2F5F7");

  // Fixes dual-screen position Most browsers Firefox
  var dualScreenLeft = window.screenLeft != undefined ? window.screenLeft : screen.left;
  var dualScreenTop = window.screenTop != undefined ? window.screenTop : screen.top;
  width = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : screen.width;
  height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height;

  var left = ((width / 2) - (w / 2)) + dualScreenLeft;
  var top = ((height / 2) - (h / 2)) + dualScreenTop;

  var newWindow = window.open(url, title, 'scrollbars=yes, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + l);
  windows[id] = newWindow;

  // Puts focus on the newWindow
  if (window.focus) {
    newWindow.focus();
  }
}

//When I tried to close this window using this function
//It is no longer working and the window is null
function closeWindow(name) {
  var window = windows[name];
  if (window) {
    window.close();
    delete windows[name];
  }
}
```

Comment: It's unlikely that the website is changing your variable. Show your code.

Comment: @Barmar yes, it is possible to clear the window. It is happening when I opened Twitter URL using window.open().

var windows = {};

var newWindow = window.open(url, title, 'scrollbars=yes, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + l);

windows[id] = newWindow;

When I access the windows[id], then window variable is null.

Comment: Put the code in the question, not a comment.

Comment: If the window is in a different domain it can't possibly access variables in your script.

Comment: Use a code block, not an image.

Comment: How do you set `id`? Is any of this code running asynchronously?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Barmar id is just an index, simply ID of the record, since I'm closing the previous window when user click on the button to open the next URL.

Comment: Well is there an error in your console?

Comment: are you reassigning `var windows = {}` every time? That will discard the old contents of `windows`.

Comment: @Barmar no error on console when executing window.close(). Please refer to the edited question. I have put the entire code. windows variable is global.

Comment: Tip: Using `window` as a variable name is ill-advised.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but you can use `value` instead of `windows[index]`

Comment: Works here: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/oa5wkvsy/5/

Comment: `if (window.focus)` should be `if (newWindow.focus)`

Comment: @Barmar It is not working with https://twitter.com/ but it's working with other sites.

Comment: Works for Twitter: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/oa5wkvsy/6/

Comment: @Barmar It gives me: twitter.com is blocked. The actual problem will occur when the twitter page loads up. I tried this on my actual project, the close window is not working, but open is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because *twitter.com* uses the "same-origin" [`cross-origin-opener-policy`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/origin.html#cross-origin-opener-policies) header.

Since your page is not from the same origin, a new *top-level browsing context* is created and your browsing context will always see this new browsing context as closed and won't be able to close it.

Comment: Thank you for this.

Comment: @IredhelPerez you're welcome. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers